# 500,000 street names - what data structure and to use to implement a fast search?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, data-structures, autocomplete

So we have many street names. They come in a file. Id probably cache them when booting the server up in production. The search should be auto complete like - e.g. you type 'lang ' and you would get maybe 8 hits : langstr, langestr. Etc

Comment: Consider a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: You might want to look at Apache Solr, it provides auto-complete OOTB without having to start from scratch.

Answer (score 10):

What you are looking for is some sort of compressed trie representation.  You might want to look into [succinct tries](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120) or [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph)s as a starting point, as they give excellent efficiency and very good space usage.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @tq- I am not familiar with mongodb, so I can't really comment on that.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete is usually implemented using one of the following:

- **Trees**. By indexing the searchable text in a tree structure (prefix tree, suffix tree, dawg, etc..) one can execute very fast searches at the expense of memory storage. The tree traversal can be adapted for approximate matching.
- **Pattern Partitioning**. By partitioning the text into tokens (ngrams) one can execute searches for pattern occurrences using a simple hashing scheme.
- **Filtering**. Find a set of potential matches and then apply a sequential algorithm to check each candidate.

Take a look at [completely](https://github.com/fmmfonseca/completely), a Java autocomplete library that implements some of the latter concepts.